# What is the equivalent of Form.IsValid() in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a WinForm with an ErrorProvider which I set like this

```
errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Error description");
```

How can I check if all the data is valid like you do in ASP.NET as Form.IsValid()?

Do I have to use errorProvider1.GetError() for every control that I validate? Is there a better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinForm UI Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769184/winform-ui-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing you will have to create yourself.
See this question [WinForm UI Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769184/winform-ui-validation)