# How to place a star mark beside a not null textbox in winform like we can do in webform

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

How to place a star mark beside a not null textbox in winform like we can do in webform. And does winform has a value-required validator like in webform ?

Comment: You can have a label with "*". Check this for validation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769184/winform-ui-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ErrorProvider` control instead. It is meant for that kind of situation.

According to MSDN: "ErrorProvider - Provides a user interface for indicating that a control on a form has an error associated with it."

You can learn how to use it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y0