# How to cause textbox validation on button click automatically in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

Windows Form Application C#

I have four `TextBox` on windows `Form`. i have written code to handle `Text_Validating` event for each textbox. Now when user clicks on submit `Button` i want those text_validating events to fire automatically.

Enabled `CausesValidation` property of Button.

We have something called validationGroup Property in ASP.net how it can be implemented in windows application

pls help me to solve this problem

thank you

Answer (score 0):

One option is simply to call the validation method passing in a parameters necessary (nulls might work - showing code would help to determine if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Text_Validating event only fires when a control's focus changes.  If you are interested in validation on submit you could do something which is proposed by user Bruce from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769184/winform-ui-validation) post.

Comment: thanx. i got `ValidateChildren()` method in the post by user Matt in the link u have given and it has solved my problem.

Comment: No problem.  Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can write own Validator controls like asp.net in `Winforms` with following validators:- .

```
RequiredFieldValidator  
RegularExpressionValidator  
CompareValidator    
RangeValidator  
CustomValidator
```

Here is a step by step explanation and walkthrough on how to extend Winforms with a custom validation library - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950965.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On button click, go with:

```
if(ValidateChildren())
{
      //do stuff
}
```