# VB6 + VB.NET lostFocus vs Validate?

Tags: vb.net, validation, vb6

I'm sure this question can apply to both, although I'm usually working with VB6 code, but why use Lost Focus vs Validate? As an example, say I need a date entered in a text box for date of birth, i want to make sure that date is entered in mm/dd/yyyy format, why would I choose to go with Validate vs Lost Focus?

Comment: In addition to Matt's answer, field by field validation isnt practical in many apps.  Validation of one control may depend on the value of another, or involve complex business rules.

Comment: I use Validate when I want to do some validation on the text and possibly PREVENT the user from moving away from the control. I generally avoid Lost Focus but might use it to adjust some trivial visual aspect of the control, like changing back colour to show where the focus is.

Comment: ...and even if you dont use a `DateTimePicker` there is no reason to be so restrictive.  `DateTime` can [parse](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WImdZ7) can parse from any legal format for a culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lost focus only fires when the user moves focus from that control to another one. The validated event fires at the point of validation. More info on validation here: [WinForm UI Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769184/winform-ui-validation)

Note that you should use a datetimepicker for date entry; that way you do not have to worry amount the format entered as it's `value` property is a `date`